# Table of contents makes pdf generation fail.

Tags: table-of-contents

I am using TeXworks to try and create a PDF file. The problem is that it seems that the `\tableofcontents` is making the pdf generation fail. Here is part of my code which seems to be causing the trouble:

```
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{entry text}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage
```

As soon as I remove that from the script, the pdf is generated. I am very new to LaTeX so I am definitely doing something that I shouldn't. Anyone can tell me what is there problem or where can I look?

I have reduced my code to this (and still managed to replicate the error

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}



\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}

\clearpage

\setcounter{page}{1}
{\Huge Sample Text}
\section{Introduction}



\section{Background}

\section{Aims and Objectives}

\section{Rationale}

\section{Methodology}

\section{Work Packages}

\section{Relevance to Beneficiaries}

\section{Justification of resources}

\begin{thebibliography}{12}

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

The error I get:

{section}{\numberline{1}Introduction}{1}
Thanks

Comment: please provide a [minimal but complete example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) which produces the error. Your given code is error free. I guess, you don't add **entry text** to the TOC. For example, if this argument contains a macro, there might be a problem.

Comment: This code contains a spurious `\end{bibliography}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there was something wrong with the LaTeX installation. I tried parsing the document with a plugin available for eclipse ([here](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/)). The document was parsed without any problems and the pdf was successfully generated.

Answer (score 2):

In your edited question, the following code line raises an error:

```
\addtocontents{toc}
```

The second mandatory argument is missing: what text should be written to the TOC.

In the first code snippet it has been correct.

In the case that you would like to use `\addtocontents` in order to change the page style within the TOC, put the command into an argument and protect it:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error: {section}{\numberline{1}Introduction}{1}

Comment: @npinti: As long as you don't post your code but some fictional code instead, I cannot really help you. Your code example doesn't contain `Introduction` like the error, for example.

Comment: The problem is that this is part of an assignment, so I can't throw my work on the net so as to avoid possible plagiarism issues. Despite the fact that I removed any section headers from my code, I am still getting that error.

Comment: @npinti: You don't need to post your content. Just make a copy, remove prose content and formulas, shrink it to get it smaller as long as the error remains, then post it. Have a serious look at [What is a minimal working example?](http://minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) to get help now and in the future. And did you follow the link in my first comment to the question?

Comment: I have edited my response. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: @npinti: Delete the `.toc` file (if it still contains an error) and compile/typeset again. When I compile your current example, it brings no error, just a warning "Empty `thebibliography` environment".